# SHELL Sorting output alphabetically

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, dash-shell

I have a script with output for example `a c d txt iso e z` I need to sort it alphabetically. These are file extensions so I cant compile it together in one word and then split up. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the output all in the same line, splited by spaces? Please consider pasting your script for better reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your the name of your script is `foo` and it writes to stdout a string such as *a c d txt iso e z*, you can get the sorted list by, for instance:

```
sorted_output=$(foo|xargs -n 1|sort)
```

Of course, depending on what you are going to do with the result, it might make more sense to store it into an array.